# How do you debug a 'No instances of ... are allowed in the image heap' when building a native image?

Tags: java, netty, graalvm-native-image

I have a little Java application that implements a RESTful API using Micronaut 2.0.0. Under the hood, it uses Redisson 3.13.1 to go to Redis. Redisson, in turn, uses Netty (4.1.49).

The application works fine in a 'classic' java (on HotSpot, both Java 8 and 11).

I'm trying to build a native image out of this application using GraalVM.

The command is *approximately* like this:

```
native-image --no-server --no-fallback -H:+TraceClassInitialization -H:+PrintClassInitialization --report-unsupported-elements-at-runtime --initialize-at-build-time=reactor.core.publisher.Flux,reactor.core.publisher.Mono -H:ConfigurationFileDirectories=target/config -cp target/app-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar com.app.AppApplication target/app
```

Here is what I get:

```
Error: Unsupported features in 4 methods
Detailed message:
Error: No instances of java.net.Inet4Address are allowed in the image heap as this class should be initialized at image runtime. Object has been initialized without the native-image initialization instrumentation and the stack trace can't be tracked.
Trace: Object was reached by 
    reading field io.netty.channel.socket.InternetProtocolFamily.localHost of
        constant io.netty.channel.socket.InternetProtocolFamily@593f1f62 reached by 
    scanning method io.netty.resolver.dns.DnsNameResolver.preferredAddressType(DnsNameResolver.java:481)
Call path from entry point to io.netty.resolver.dns.DnsNameResolver.preferredAddressType(ResolvedAddressTypes): 
    at io.netty.resolver.dns.DnsNameResolver.preferredAddressType(DnsNameResolver.java:478)
    at io.netty.resolver.dns.DnsNameResolver.<init>(DnsNameResolver.java:436)
    at io.netty.resolver.dns.DnsNameResolverBuilder.build(DnsNameResolverBuilder.java:473)
    at io.netty.resolver.dns.DnsAddressResolverGroup.newNameResolver(DnsAddressResolverGroup.java:111)
    at io.netty.resolver.dns.DnsAddressResolverGroup.newResolver(DnsAddressResolverGroup.java:91)
    at io.netty.resolver.dns.DnsAddressResolverGroup.newResolver(DnsAddressResolverGroup.java:76)
    at io.netty.resolver.AddressResolverGroup.getResolver(AddressResolverGroup.java:70)
    at org.redisson.cluster.ClusterConnectionManager$1.run(ClusterConnectionManager.java:251)
    at com.oracle.svm.core.jdk.RuntimeSupport.executeHooks(RuntimeSupport.java:125)
    at com.oracle.svm.core.jdk.RuntimeSupport.executeStartupHooks(RuntimeSupport.java:75)
    at com.oracle.svm.core.JavaMainWrapper.runCore(JavaMainWrapper.java:141)
    at com.oracle.svm.core.JavaMainWrapper.run(JavaMainWrapper.java:184)
    at com.oracle.svm.core.code.IsolateEnterStub.JavaMainWrapper_run_5087f5482cc9a6abc971913ece43acb471d2631b(generated:0)
```

That's just a part of the output, it also produces similar reports on other 3 errors.

I'm still struggling to understand the issue, but I suppose that, as `java.net.InetAddress` has native methods in it, neither it nor its subclass `java.net.Inet4Address` can be initialized at build time. This means that an instance of `Inet4Address` cannot be visible for a code that is initialized at build time (at initialization stage, in Java terms). And the native image builder found a way that kinda reaches a point where such an object is visible. It even shows the trace, but the thing is that `ClusterConnectionManager$1` is a `Runnable` that is only submitted to an `Executor` at runtime (waaaay after the static initialization).

How do you debug such situations? Namely:

1. How do you find the culprit?
2. How do you fix it when the culprit is found?

PS. If I add `--initialize-at-run-time=java.net.InetAddress`, it fails differently:

```
Error: The class java.net.InetAddress has already been initialized; it is too late 
to register java.net.InetAddress for build-time initialization (from the command 
line). java.net.InetAddress has been initialized without the native-image 
initialization instrumentation and the stack trace can't be tracked. Try avoiding 
this conflict by avoiding to initialize the class that caused initialization of 
java.net.InetAddress or by not marking java.net.InetAddress for build-time 
initialization.
```

Java reports itself as `build 25.252-b09-jvmci-20.1-b02, mixed mode`.

PPS. I found this [No instances of ... are allowed in the image heap as this class should be initialized at image runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59011565/no-instances-of-are-allowed-in-the-image-heap-as-this-class-should-be-initia) and it seems that the Quarkus issue was fixed. But I still do not understand how to fix the issue at hand. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

**TLDR;** there is a small section with a summary at the end of the answer.

## A bit of theory

In Java, every class must be initialized before usage. Initialization means executing static field initializers
and static initialization blocks. In a standard JVM (like HotSpot), this happens at runtime, of course.

But with a native image, you have two alternatives. A class may still be initialized at runtime, or its initialization
may be carried out at build time. The latter has an obvious benefit of avoiding this work at native image startup,
which makes the image start faster. But for some classes it does not make sense to initialize them at build time.
Such an example could be a class that makes some decisions in its initialization (create an instance of this or that
class, for example) based on environment (env variables, config files, etc).

There are some restrictions in regard to choosing between build/run time initialization alternatives:

- If a class is initialized at build time, all of its superclasses must be initialized at build time
- If a class is initialized at run time, all of its subclasses must be initialized at runtime
- Some classes must always be initialized at runtime (see below)
- An instance of a class that is initialized at runtime cannot exist in *image heap* (this means that **no
  build-time initialized class or its instance can (directly or indirectly) reference such a runtime-initialized
  class instance**)

### InetAddress issue

Since version 19.3.0, `native-image` tool requires that `java.net.InetAddress` class is always initialized at runtime.
This (by restriction 2) means that its subclasses, `java.net.Inet4Address` and `java.net.Inet6Address` must also be
initialized at runtime, which in turn (by restriction 4) means that you cannot have any `InetAddress` referenced
by a build-time initialized class.

All the build failures we encounter here are caused by this same problem: either `Inet4Address` or `Inet6Address`
in image heap.

## But why are Netty-related classes tried to be initialized at build time?

It turns out that `netty-codec-http` contains the following

```
Args = --initialize-at-build-time=io.netty \
```

in its `native-image.properties` below `META-INF`, and micronaut has `netty-codec-http` as a dependency, so all
`io.netty` classes are by default initialized at build time (as `native-image` tool respects such
`native-image.properties` files).

## A model project

Here https://github.com/rpuch/netty-InetAddress-native-image-diagnosing is a project that models the problem and which
I further use to show how to solve the problem. Its `main()` method follows:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    NioEventLoopGroup group = new NioEventLoopGroup(1, new DefaultThreadFactory("netty"));

    DnsAddressResolverGroup resolverGroup = new DnsAddressResolverGroup(NioDatagramChannel.class,
            DnsServerAddressStreamProviders.platformDefault());
    AddressResolver<InetSocketAddress> resolver = resolverGroup.getResolver(group.next());
    System.out.println(resolver);

    resolver.close();
    group.shutdownGracefully().get();
}
```

It causes the same effects (regarding Netty) that the following code does:

```
    Config config = new Config();
    config.useSingleServer().setAddress(redisUri);
    config.useSingleServer().setPassword(redisPassword);

    return Redisson.createReactive(config);
```

This project also has `--initialize-at-build-time=io.netty` in its build script to emulate micronaut-based project
behavior.

So it is a useful substitute for the original project that brought this question to light.

## GraalVM version

I'm using version 20.2.0 here (the most recent released version as of the moment of writing).

## Diagnosing and fixing

### 1

Build fails with the following error:

```
Error: com.oracle.graal.pointsto.constraints.UnsupportedFeatureException: No instances of java.net.Inet4Address are allowed in the image heap as this class should be initialized at image runtime. Object has been initialized without the native-image initialization instrumentation and the stack trace can't be tracked.
Trace:
    at parsing io.netty.resolver.dns.DnsNameResolver.resolveHostsFileEntry(DnsNameResolver.java:659)
Call path from entry point to io.netty.resolver.dns.DnsNameResolver.resolveHostsFileEntry(String):
    at io.netty.resolver.dns.DnsNameResolver.resolveHostsFileEntry(DnsNameResolver.java:651)
    at io.netty.resolver.dns.DnsNameResolver.doResolve(DnsNameResolver.java:884)
    at io.netty.resolver.dns.DnsNameResolver.doResolve(DnsNameResolver.java:733)
    at io.netty.resolver.SimpleNameResolver.resolve(SimpleNameResolver.java:61)
    at io.netty.resolver.SimpleNameResolver.resolve(SimpleNameResolver.java:53)
    at io.netty.resolver.InetSocketAddressResolver.doResolve(InetSocketAddressResolver.java:55)
    at io.netty.resolver.InetSocketAddressResolver.doResolve(InetSocketAddressResolver.java:31)
    at io.netty.resolver.AbstractAddressResolver.resolve(AbstractAddressResolver.java:106)
    at io.netty.bootstrap.Bootstrap.doResolveAndConnect0(Bootstrap.java:206)
    at io.netty.bootstrap.Bootstrap.access$000(Bootstrap.java:46)
    at io.netty.bootstrap.Bootstrap$1.operationComplete(Bootstrap.java:180)
```

`DnsNameResolver:659` is

```
return LOCALHOST_ADDRESS;
```

and it references the static field named `LOCALHOST_ADDRESS` of type `InetAddress`. Let's avoid its initialization
at build time by adding the following to the `native-image` command`:

```
--initialize-at-run-time=io.netty.resolver.dns.DnsNameResolver
```

The error goes away.

### 2

Now there is another one:

```
Error: No instances of java.net.Inet6Address are allowed in the image heap as this class should be initialized at image runtime. Object has been initialized without the native-image initialization instrumentation and the stack trace can't be tracked.
Trace: Object was reached by
    reading field java.util.HashMap$Node.value of
        constant java.util.HashMap$Node@26eb0f30 reached by
    indexing into array
        constant java.util.HashMap$Node[]@63e95621 reached by
    reading field java.util.HashMap.table of
        constant java.util.HashMap@563992d1 reached by
    reading field java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableMap.m of
        constant java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableMap@38a9945c reached by
    reading field io.netty.resolver.DefaultHostsFileEntriesResolver.inet6Entries of
        constant io.netty.resolver.DefaultHostsFileEntriesResolver@7ef4ba7e reached by
    scanning method io.netty.resolver.dns.DnsNameResolverBuilder.<init>(DnsNameResolverBuilder.java:56)
Call path from entry point to io.netty.resolver.dns.DnsNameResolverBuilder.<init>():
    at io.netty.resolver.dns.DnsNameResolverBuilder.<init>(DnsNameResolverBuilder.java:68)
    at io.netty.resolver.dns.DnsAddressResolverGroup.<init>(DnsAddressResolverGroup.java:54)
    at Main.main(Main.java:18)
```

`DnsNameResolverBuilder:56` is

```
private HostsFileEntriesResolver hostsFileEntriesResolver = HostsFileEntriesResolver.DEFAULT;
```

Let's postpone `HostsFileEntriesResolver` initialization:

```
--initialize-at-run-time=io.netty.resolver.HostsFileEntriesResolver
```

### 3

Now, there is another error:

```
Error: com.oracle.graal.pointsto.constraints.UnsupportedFeatureException: No instances of java.net.Inet6Address are allowed in the image heap as this class should be initialized at image runtime. Object has been initialized without the native-image initialization instrumentation and the stack trace can't be tracked.
Trace:
    at parsing io.netty.resolver.dns.DnsQueryContextManager.getOrCreateContextMap(DnsQueryContextManager.java:111)
Call path from entry point to io.netty.resolver.dns.DnsQueryContextManager.getOrCreateContextMap(InetSocketAddress):
    at io.netty.resolver.dns.DnsQueryContextManager.getOrCreateContextMap(DnsQueryContextManager.java:96)
```

`DnsQueryContextManager:111` references `NetUtil.LOCALHOST6`. `NetUtil` is initialized at build time, but its fields
`LOCALHOST4` and `LOCALHOST6` contain instances of `Inet4Address` and `Inet6Address`, respectively. This can be solved
by a *substitution*. We just add the following class to our project:

```
@TargetClass(NetUtil.class)
final class NetUtilSubstitutions {
    @Alias
    @InjectAccessors(NetUtilLocalhost4Accessor.class)
    public static Inet4Address LOCALHOST4;

    @Alias
    @InjectAccessors(NetUtilLocalhost6Accessor.class)
    public static Inet6Address LOCALHOST6;

    private static class NetUtilLocalhost4Accessor {
        static Inet4Address get() {
            // using https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Initialization-on-demand_holder_idiom
            return NetUtilLocalhost4LazyHolder.LOCALHOST4;
        }

        static void set(Inet4Address ignored) {
            // a no-op setter to avoid exceptions when NetUtil is initialized at run-time
        }
    }

    private static class NetUtilLocalhost4LazyHolder {
        private static final Inet4Address LOCALHOST4;

        static {
            byte[] LOCALHOST4_BYTES = {127, 0, 0, 1};
            // Create IPv4 loopback address.
            try {
                LOCALHOST4 = (Inet4Address) InetAddress.getByAddress("localhost", LOCALHOST4_BYTES);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // We should not get here as long as the length of the address is correct.
                PlatformDependent.throwException(e);
                throw new IllegalStateException("Should not reach here");
            }
        }
    }

    private static class NetUtilLocalhost6Accessor {
        static Inet6Address get() {
            // using https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Initialization-on-demand_holder_idiom
            return NetUtilLocalhost6LazyHolder.LOCALHOST6;
        }

        static void set(Inet6Address ignored) {
            // a no-op setter to avoid exceptions when NetUtil is initialized at run-time
        }
    }
    
    private static class NetUtilLocalhost6LazyHolder {
        private static final Inet6Address LOCALHOST6;

        static {
            byte[] LOCALHOST6_BYTES = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1};
            // Create IPv6 loopback address.
            try {
                LOCALHOST6 = (Inet6Address) InetAddress.getByAddress("localhost", LOCALHOST6_BYTES);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // We should not get here as long as the length of the address is correct.
                PlatformDependent.throwException(e);
                throw new IllegalStateException("Should not reach here");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The idea is to replace loads of the problematic fields with method invocations controlled by us. This is achieved
via a substitution (note `@TargetClass`, `@Alias` and `@InjectAccessors`). As a result, the `InetAddress` values
are not stored in image heap anymore. The error goes away.

### 4

We now have another one:

```
Error: No instances of java.net.Inet6Address are allowed in the image heap as this class should be initialized at image runtime. Object has been initialized without the native-image initialization instrumentation and the stack trace can't be tracked.
Trace: Object was reached by
    reading field io.netty.channel.socket.InternetProtocolFamily.localHost of
        constant io.netty.channel.socket.InternetProtocolFamily@5dc39065 reached by
    scanning method io.netty.resolver.dns.DnsNameResolver.preferredAddressType(DnsNameResolver.java:487)
Call path from entry point to io.netty.resolver.dns.DnsNameResolver.preferredAddressType(ResolvedAddressTypes):
    at io.netty.resolver.dns.DnsNameResolver.preferredAddressType(DnsNameResolver.java:481)
```

As it can be seen from the code of `InternetProtocolFamily`, each enum constant stores an instance of `InetAddress`,
so if any class initialized at build time initializes `InternetProtocolFamily`, the image heap gets polluted with
`InetAddress` instance. This can also be solved with a substitution:

```
@TargetClass(InternetProtocolFamily.class)
final class InternetProtocolFamilySubstitutions {
    @Alias
    @InjectAccessors(InternetProtocolFamilyLocalhostAccessor.class)
    private InetAddress localHost;

    private static class InternetProtocolFamilyLocalhostAccessor {
        static InetAddress get(InternetProtocolFamily family) {
            switch (family) {
                case IPv4:
                    return NetUtil.LOCALHOST4;
                case IPv6:
                    return NetUtil.LOCALHOST6;
                default:
                    throw new IllegalStateException("Unsupported internet protocol family: " + family);
            }
        }

        static void set(InternetProtocolFamily family, InetAddress address) {
            // storing nothing as the getter derives all it needs from its argument
        }
    }
}
```

The error goes away.

### 5

There is another one this time:

```
Error: No instances of java.net.Inet4Address are allowed in the image heap as this class should be initialized at image runtime. Object has been initialized without the native-image initialization instrumentation and the stack trace can't be tracked.
Detailed message:
Trace: Object was reached by
    reading field java.net.InetSocketAddress$InetSocketAddressHolder.addr of
        constant java.net.InetSocketAddress$InetSocketAddressHolder@34913c36 reached by
    reading field java.net.InetSocketAddress.holder of
        constant java.net.InetSocketAddress@ad1fe10 reached by
    reading field io.netty.resolver.dns.SingletonDnsServerAddresses.address of
        constant io.netty.resolver.dns.SingletonDnsServerAddresses@79fd599 reached by
    scanning method io.netty.resolver.dns.DefaultDnsServerAddressStreamProvider.nameServerAddressStream(DefaultDnsServerAddressStreamProvider.java:115)
Call path from entry point to io.netty.resolver.dns.DefaultDnsServerAddressStreamProvider.nameServerAddressStream(String):
    at io.netty.resolver.dns.DefaultDnsServerAddressStreamProvider.nameServerAddressStream(DefaultDnsServerAddressStreamProvider.java:115)
    at io.netty.resolver.dns.DnsServerAddressStreamProviders$DefaultProviderHolder$1.nameServerAddressStream(DnsServerAddressStreamProviders.java:131)
    at io.netty.resolver.dns.DnsNameResolver.doResolveAllUncached0(DnsNameResolver.java:1070)
```

First, let's move initialization of `io.netty.resolver.dns.DefaultDnsServerAddressStreamProvider` to
run-time:

```
--initialize-at-run-time=io.netty.resolver.dns.DefaultDnsServerAddressStreamProvider
```

Now, the error is similar, but still slightly different:

```
Error: No instances of java.net.Inet4Address are allowed in the image heap as this class should be initialized at image runtime. Object has been initialized without the native-image initialization instrumentation and the stack trace can't be tracked.
Trace: Object was reached by
    reading field java.net.InetSocketAddress$InetSocketAddressHolder.addr of
        constant java.net.InetSocketAddress$InetSocketAddressHolder@5537c5de reached by
    reading field java.net.InetSocketAddress.holder of
        constant java.net.InetSocketAddress@fb954f8 reached by
    reading field io.netty.resolver.dns.SingletonDnsServerAddresses.address of
        constant io.netty.resolver.dns.SingletonDnsServerAddresses@3ec9baab reached by
    reading field io.netty.resolver.dns.UnixResolverDnsServerAddressStreamProvider.defaultNameServerAddresses of
        constant io.netty.resolver.dns.UnixResolverDnsServerAddressStreamProvider@1b7f0339 reached by
    reading field io.netty.resolver.dns.DnsServerAddressStreamProviders$DefaultProviderHolder$1.currentProvider of
        constant io.netty.resolver.dns.DnsServerAddressStreamProviders$DefaultProviderHolder$1@2d249be7 reached by
    scanning method io.netty.resolver.dns.DnsServerAddressStreamProviders.unixDefault(DnsServerAddressStreamProviders.java:104)
Call path from entry point to io.netty.resolver.dns.DnsServerAddressStreamProviders.unixDefault():
    at io.netty.resolver.dns.DnsServerAddressStreamProviders.unixDefault(DnsServerAddressStreamProviders.java:104)
    at io.netty.resolver.dns.DnsServerAddressStreamProviders.platformDefault(DnsServerAddressStreamProviders.java:100)
    at Main.main(Main.java:18)
```

Ok, let's move initialization of `io.netty.resolver.dns.DnsServerAddressStreamProviders$DefaultProviderHolder` to
run-time as well:

```
'--initialize-at-run-time=io.netty.resolver.dns.DnsServerAddressStreamProviders$DefaultProviderHolder'
```

(note the single quotes: without them `$` and characters following it will be interpreted by `sh` and replaced with an
empty string).

The error goes away.

> Please note that the order turned out to be important here. When I first moved
> `io.netty.resolver.dns.DnsServerAddressStreamProviders$DefaultProviderHolder` initialization to run-time but did not
> touch `io.netty.resolver.dns.DefaultDnsServerAddressStreamProvider` initialization, the error report did not change
> a bit. So it takes a little patience and experimenting (or some knowledge which I do not have, alas).

Now we have this:

```
Error: com.oracle.graal.pointsto.constraints.UnsupportedFeatureException: No instances of java.net.Inet6Address are allowed in the image heap as this class should be initialized at image runtime. Object has been initialized without the native-image initialization instrumentation and the stack trace can't be tracked.
Detailed message:
Trace:
    at parsing io.netty.resolver.dns.DefaultDnsServerAddressStreamProvider.<clinit>(DefaultDnsServerAddressStreamProvider.java:87)
Call path from entry point to io.netty.resolver.dns.DefaultDnsServerAddressStreamProvider.<clinit>():
    no path found from entry point to target method
```

Ok, it's `NetUtil.LOCALHOST` being referenced, so let's add a substitution for it as well (to `NetUtilSubstitutions`):

```
@Alias
@InjectAccessors(NetUtilLocalhostAccessor.class)
public static InetAddress LOCALHOST;

// NOTE: this is the simpliest implementation I could invent to just demonstrate the idea; it is probably not
// too efficient. An efficient implementation would only have getter and it would compute the InetAddress
// there; but the post is already very long, and NetUtil.LOCALHOST computation logic in Netty is rather cumbersome.
private static class NetUtilLocalhostAccessor {
    private static volatile InetAddress ADDR;

    static InetAddress get() {
        return ADDR;
    }

    static void set(InetAddress addr) {
        ADDR = addr;
    }
}
```

This makes the final error go away.

> Thanks to @NicolasFilotto for suggestions on item 5, I like his solution a lot more than the original, and actually
> item 5 is an implementation of his ideas.

## Summary of techniques

1. First of all, you could find a class that, being moved to runtime initialization phase, makes a failure to go away.
   To do this, you could trace references in the provided stack trace. Best candidates to consider are static fields.
2. If item 1 does not help, you could try to create a substitution
3. There is also a theoretical possibility to go with a lighter variant: `@RecomputeFieldValue`, but it's more
   restricted, and I could not make it work in this Netty-related task.

PS. Substitution-related code is inspired by https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/pull/5353/files

PPS. Item 5 solution is inspired by @NicolasFilotto

Comment: Very nice answer, thank you for sharing. I could make it compile with `--initialize-at-run-time` on `io.netty.resolver.dns.DefaultDnsServerAddressStreamProvider` and `io.netty.resolver.dns.DnsServerAddressStreamProviders\$DefaultProviderHolder` (note the backslash before the dollar character) and a new `InjectAccessors` on `LOCALHOST` of `NetUtil` instead of a substitution of `SingletonDnsServerAddresses`. I don't know if it is a better approach. Another remark, is-it possible to use https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Initialization-on-demand_holder_idiom instead of `double-checked locking`

Comment: Another question, do you have a link to the doc about substitutions to share?

Comment: What an excellent answer! I learned a lot from it, thanks!

Comment: @NicolasFilotto thank you for your comments and suggestions! I hope you don't mind that I incorporated your solution of `SingletonDnsServerAddresses` problem into the answer (I like your approach more because it avoids to initialize at build time things that depend on the runtime environment).
I also applied your suggestion about 'initialization on demand holder', it makes the code cleaner (and probably more efficient).
Alas, all the information sources I had were that commit in Quarkus (mentioned in the answer) and javadocs on `@TargetClass` and other annotations in its package.